# Loop matrices into a structure

Tags: matlab, loops, structure

I'm not even sure if the title describes what I want to do, so let me try to elaborate.

Each iteration of the loop creates an `X` matrix. As it stands now, only the final iteration of the `X` matrix remains after the loop finishes. 
However my desired final output is 6 `X` matrices. One for each of the loop iterations.

Basically, I want to save all 6 of the `X` matrices, not overwrite them after each iteration.

```
for col=2:7
    logprice=log(ret(1:end,col));
    logret=diff(logprice);
    exret=logret-logRFree;
    price_mat(:,col-1)=logprice; 
    ret_mat(:,col-1)=logret;
    exret_mat(:,col-1)=exret;

    X=[ret_mat(:,col-1) termspread creditspread inflation realrate ];   

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the size of `X` is different on each iteration (and it looks that way), it may be easiest to store them in a cell array:

```
% before loop
X = cell(N,1);
% in loop, with a counter ii ...
X{ii} = [...];
```

If the `X` matrix were the same size on each iteration of the loop, you could preallocate a 3D array and save to each slice (e.g. `X=zeros(R,C,P); ... X(:,:,ii) = [...];`);

Answer (score 1):

There are two most common ways. [Cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) is one of them. The other one is 3-D matrices. It can be generalized to n-D matrices too.

Cell arrays can handle different size of matrix X on every iteration. 3-D matrices cannot. All matrices have to be of the same size. You can pre-allocate cells as well as 3-D matrices to save execution time on large loops. Also, it is a good practice to follow.

1. [Preallocate cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocate-memory-for-a-cell-array.html)
2. [Preallocate matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html)

It can be done as follows:

```
count=0;
for col=2:7
    count=count+1;
    logprice=log(ret(1:end,col));
    logret=diff(logprice);
    exret=logret-logRFree;
    price_mat(:,col-1)=logprice; 
    ret_mat(:,col-1)=logret;
    exret_mat(:,col-1)=exret;

    %%%%%%Execute only one of the following two statements%%%%%%%
    X{count}=[ret_mat(:,col-1) termspread creditspread inflation realrate ];   
    X(:,:,count)=[ret_mat(:,col-1) termspread creditspread inflation realrate ];
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
end
```